# Upgrading Angular 2.0.0 to 2.x.x

Tags: angularjs, angular, upgrade, angular2-upgrade

Currently our application is on the Angular 2.0 version.
How important is it to keep updating it as and when Angular releases a new update?

In the changelog i dont see any breaking changes that need to be addressed immediately going from 2.0.0 to 2.4.2.

So is it necessary to upgrade our application from 2.0.0 to 2.4.2? Or should we just wait till there is another big release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest upgrading to newer version of major release when:

- You came across the issue/bug which was fixed in newer version.
- There's a new feature which will come in handy.
- Changes positively affecting performance - e.g. AOT compiler which can be a deal breaker to some people, but it might require some code to be rewritten to make it AOT-friendly.

Answer (score 4):

Angular uses semantic versioning. Going from 2.0.x to 2.0.y means that a bug has been fixed. It's usually a good idea to avoid having bugs. Going from 2.0.y to 2.1.0 means that a new feature is available. You might want or need to benefit from this new feature.

You won't have any breaking change until the next major version, which will be 4.0.0 (there won't be a 3.x version, in order to align angular and its router versions)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#best-practices) under *Best Practices Section*

> **Best practices**
>
> - **Keep current with the latest Angular library releases**. We regularly    update our Angular libraries, and these updates may fix security
>     defects discovered in previous versions. Check the Angular change log 
>     for security-related updates.
> - **Don't modify your copy of Angular.** Private, customized versions of       Angular tend to fall behind the current version and may not include
>     important security fixes and enhancements. Instead, share your
>     Angular improvements with the community and make a pull request.
> - **Avoid Angular APIs marked in the documentation as “Security Risk.”**